# Why very large string throws java.lang.StackOverflow Exception when validated against XSS attack pattern

Tags: java, regex, stack-overflow

My requirement is that,i  am using white list Regex pattern to avoid xss and sql injection so as my allowed character in string is `([A-Za-z0-9,\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\"\\:./_\\s]|(?<!-)-)*`

In short it below test cases should run successfully

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;   
public class XSSAttackTest {

    private static Pattern xssAttackPattern;

    private static final String XSS_ATTACK_REGULAR_EXPRESSION1 = "([A-Za-z0-9,\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\"\\:./_\\s]|(?<!-)-)*";

    public static Pattern getXSSAttackPattern() {
        xssAttackPattern = Pattern.compile(XSS_ATTACK_REGULAR_EXPRESSION1);
        return xssAttackPattern;
    }

    public static boolean hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection1(String value) {

        if (getXSSAttackPattern().matcher(value).matches()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        System.out.println(" :::::: Regular Expression ::::::");
        XSSAttackTest();

    }

    private static void XSSAttackTest() {

        String jsonWithoutDobuleQuote = "{systemaddress:10:9A:DD:54:BA:3F,name:0541cb61fe0c37002f15df342df18a912689875f75159335d936e281f9098a78c598334cf59dc9bcf55dd4614097effd874194b47d19194b5e7d0aa3a61290a2b5e90323ef3967571499a820af8424f935b35c36ea34fd83b08fdf14c3b454c6962b36e9de4b1bc75e793832b59efb9648cb04f7153e0b3c1c648e64154d9b05,number:c097a8c8a481e0b50911d96b8d15ca326bcb47c1056cfae7552f23fa6ba179bf48c4b32aecd42e23c76b148e057ce0acdacba8fb7cf93619aca18b7dfcf931511b7b7889db2703ec9b48fe68c713205f5333ffc4abbce8489d32fe6a54c518d24a1774f864964379497276f38d7b8611d54c035339922efe9ea0b1b4266a1d64,zip:521bf5503247d51cf2a2997fc7e2fd7055cb62c352bb1bacbf4d8af0e45984ab8becb4ce4ef824b2740591574317a6548231b831f2b2b73421d25a2b979ce10cebe4b52f555793909cbfa09d9617d4fdba4632f896bd43113381dea8cbc66cc8bb5cffdbd3d45b73d9e6dfb56b998f5e44568e9e7a419c75998acd3d5898f048,ssn:98c07a39f46b6fcbcc331510cb698f2fc331590b4033ef51ff86649283e99396aa48769b563511978fce652f41be98d326a62033176f9a5bfccfd9270e69316ebe3f6152d280bc83782c31d17c4b5d34df7c3107601bb5bb19968056d921b435aa62fc0855c5c57f249eedc9bb581379def31354d5afab5180c8ab63ac7a743e,Provider:xyz,deviceModel:iPhone Simulator,id:1731368714731871}";

        System.out.println("String::" + jsonWithoutDobuleQuote + "::Result::"
                + hasXSSAttackOrSQLInjection1(jsonWithoutDobuleQuote));

    }
}
```

When i run above code throw below exception, here i am try to check that given string in code contain XSS prone characters or not

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern$6.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:4763)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$6.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:4763)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$6.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:4763)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$6.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:4763)
```

Comment: because you are using a bad regex.

Comment: I don't get any exception with your code.

Comment: @Woot4Moo -  would you please provide good regex pattern which give me same output as old one pattern, my pattern contain white list character.

Comment: @Mateusz : once again i tried that code and run as java application and i am still getting same exception.

Comment: Arjun I would not roll my own security as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - On what basis you consider as bad regex ? i am questioning just bcz to get know how about regex bad and good aspect.

Comment: @ArjunSolanki: I don't know what kind of bad Woot4Moo is referring to, but your regex is not optimized so it causes the StackOverflowError. That aside, when you roll your own security mechanism, if you yourself cannot **prove** ("believe" and "think" are out of the question here) that it is safe, then you should not use it.

Comment: might be this one: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6337993

Answer (score 1):

This is a primary example of why you should not roll your own security mechanism.  You want to use the OWASP projects to solve this type of problem.

[documentation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
 example:

```
 String safe = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute  
         ( request.getParameter( "input" ) );
```

and a sanitizer:

```
  import org.owasp.html.Sanitizers;
  import org.owasp.html.PolicyFactory;
  PolicyFactory sanitizer = Sanitizers.FORMATTING.and(Sanitizers.BLOCKS);
  String cleanResults = sanitizer.sanitize("<p>Hello, <b>World!</b>");
```

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with the first statement (not roll your own security mechanism), but how does the code apply to OP's situation?

Comment: @nhahtdh ah great question, I was illustrating what is available in the OWASP package, which OP should be using anyways.  And to demonstrate the techniques that can be used.  The fundamental problem is that OP is using an invalid regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh : what's "OP" means ?

Comment: @ArjunSolanki: [What does "OP" mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op) I am referring to you.

Comment: @nhahtdh : what's full form of "OP".

Comment: @Woot4Moo - very nice, thanks for such security guidance. In my case i need some another white list regex pattern which should not throw above exception, In past i am facing same issue, but just change in regex pattern(whitelist), it was resolved, can you suggest me another regex pattern ?

Comment: Any one can suggest me alternative regex pattern for given regex pattern ?